# Save Excel as Image in SQL Server Field

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, excel

I am converting an MS Access 2003 application to C# (VS 2010) and SQL Server 2008.

It's all pretty basic except for one thing. I've got embedded excel spreadsheets in the application. In Access they are edited and saved as OLE DB objects. The spreadsheet is then displayed as an image in the report. I have converted the Access Reports to Crystal Reports and converted data shows just fine in the reports.

I can create the spreadsheet and save it to a file, but what I can't figure out is how to create and save an Excel Spreadsheet as an image in my SQL Server field so Crystal can put it in the report.

I also know images are deprecated in SS 2008 so any ideas on how to move my whole report to something else would be appreciated.

FYI: An older post suggested Lenni Lobel's articles, but they are not there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are two requirements here:

1. Be able to access the file data via Crystal
2. Be able to efficiently store a spreadsheet in a SQL Server 2012 database column.

Your choices (other than Image columns) would appear to be FileStream and VarBinary.  Here's a comparison:   [VARBINARY vs. FILESTREAM](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/01/sql-server-varbinary-vs-filestream-code.html).

I can't comment on Crystal's ability to access either of those, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Ann..... I've been able to do 1 and 2. What I can't do is figure out (via OLE DB?) how to store the spreadsheet as an image. It seems like in Access the OLE object was both a spreadsheet AND an image. Since it's Access 2003 I was hoping someone would have some links to some old OLE object reading and writing. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "an image", do you mean an actual visual representation of the appearance of the spreadsheet?  And Crystal was able to treat the object as an image and display it in some kind of image control?  Interesting ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use OLE object in Crystal reports to show the excel file (without saving it as a picture) This will probably work fine for all computers where Excel is installed.